# Pass a Selenium WebElement to WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click a Javascript link, but I can't get it to work.
First I'm getting list of Links using this code:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[@class='market-box-wp collapse in'])[1]//a[@class='truncate']")
```

then trying to click some of them

```
links[3].click() #Doesn't work
```

I found this solution online for Javascript links, but it's using xPath, not sure how to pass links[3] to it:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"Xpath of Element"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **xpath** `indexing` :-

see this is the **xpath**

```
(//div[@class='market-box-wp collapse in'])[1]//a[@class='truncate']
```

Now to locate the **3rd item**, you could do this :

```
((//div[@class='market-box-wp collapse in'])[1]//a[@class='truncate'])[3]
```

and use it like this :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"((//div[@class='market-box-wp collapse in'])[1]//a[@class='truncate'])[3]"))).click()
```